# Action of the multiplicative group induced by a grading

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, group-actions, graded-rings, graded-algebras

I found in several different fonts, (in the first section of this (https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9405004) paper, or even in this answer (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212960/intuition-behind-basic-facts-about-homogeneous-ideals) here in MSE) the following claim

Let $X$ be an affine variety and $A$ its coordinate ring. Then to give a  $\mathbb{Z}$ grading on $A$ is equivalent to give a  $\mathbb{G}_m=k^{\times}$ action on $X$.

This fact seems to be well known although I did not find any book or paper that proves it. Does anyone know a reference?

For one side if one has a $\mathbb{G}_m=k^{\times}$ action on $X$, it is easy to build a $\mathbb{Z}-$grading on $A$. One considers the following action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on $A$, if $f \in A$ then  $t.f(x) = f(t^{-1}.x)$. In this way, the grading on $A$ will be given by  $A_d = \{f\in A; t.f = t^nf\}$.

My problem is on the other side. I can not prove that if I have a $\mathbb{Z}$ grading on $A$, then I can found an action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on $X$. Is there something easy that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to define your action of $\Bbb G_m$ by $\lambda$ acting on the $d$-graded piece by $\lambda^d$?

Comment: Dear @KReiser, considering a point $p \in X = Spec~A$, we have that $p$ is a prime ideal in $A$ then if $p$ is homogeneous it follows that $p = \oplus A_d \cap p$ and then the action could be $t.p =  \oplus t^dA_d \cap p$. But I don't know how to proceed with the case where $p$ is not homogeneous. Do you have any thoughts?